# Google Play Games fails to sign-in at the first attemp, success at the second

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm experiencing a really silly problem in the Google Play Games API, when a user joins, he needs to click the sign in again to be signed-in.

I have the auto-sign in at startup, so when the user opens the app, it shows the sign-in dialog, choose an email, then closes without any message, after that the user must click on the sign in again to be signed.

So, it's unknown why its happening, the popular problem that people are having is not signing in, but this is failing at the first attemp.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements
    View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{ 

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();

}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, 2);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivityForResult(null, 3);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` in your `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

As otherwise the result from `connectionResult.startResolutionForResult` does not update the `GoogleApiClient` state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there's one thing to keep in mind, when there is no WiFi or there's an error in signing-in, it will loop the SIGN-IN thing over and over, is there a better way to handle this loop than using a boolean ?

Comment: You'd probably want the more robust code that they go through on the [initializing Play Games guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) which uses two booleans, `mAutoStartSignInflow` and `mSignInClicked` as guards for doing work on `onConnectionFailed`.